Having issue in writing cookie data to file using PHP Version 8 curl
I am trying to save cookie data when calling a page using CURL. When I run the same code on Server 1 then it works and if I run it on Server 2 then it doesn't work.
Server 1 Detail
PHP Version 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.17
cURL Information 7.58.0
Server 2 Detail
PHP Version 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.17
cURL Information 7.81.0
Here is my code
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/var/www/html/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/var/www/html/cookie.txt");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);//only used on Server 1
unset($ch);//only used on Server 2


Did you check file permissions?

CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR is for saving cookies, whereas CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE is for loading them. Why are you using both? Why use CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER and get $output if you want to save cookie data?

@KIKOSoftware It's normal to use both. You send the old cookies, then save the returned cookies, just like a browser would.

@MarkusZeller Yes I have checked the file permission and I am able to write using file_put_contents

@KIKOSoftware You'r right. I am using both just like browser works.

Try to debug via using curl_getinfo($ch); after the exec and var_dump the results.

hey I had already checked it but it didn't worked. I have checked on multiple PHP version on multiple server and it worked. Now I am going to relaunch new server and test.
